# HP Fortify SCC - Rulepacks

Tags: fortify

How are rulepacks named? For example, I see 5 rulepacks in my Administration View on Software Security Center ("SSC"). The rulepacks are named for .NET or Java in the names.

Do the rulepack names have a 1 to 1 relationship with the analysis being conducted? Should there be a Abap, C++ or Python rulepack if I wanted the Dashboard to display an analysis of those languages?

Answer (score 1):

The five rulepacks you see in SSC that cannot be deleted, are the "Runtime" rules. SCA rules are different, and are not included with the base SSC install.  You have to click the rulepack update button to get them from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

(1) HP factory rulepack should be installed to ~FORTIFY_HOME/Core/config/rules directory. you can check the version by command:

UNIX: grep -n -binary  Version= /local/ssap/fortify-sca-3.80/Core/config/rules/*.bin

WINDOW: findstr /C:"Version=" d:\fortify\Core\config\rules*.bin

(2) You can delete the .bin files which your application does not use (i.e. SAP abap, coldfusion, python...). feel free to add your custom_rule.xml to this folder.

(3) The rulepack should be installed to the server running ~/bin/sourceanalyzer. The rule files you see in the SSC admin dashboard is for users to download/update the rulepack only. If you don't scan on the SSC server and you distribute the rulepack by email the .zip file to users, you don't need to import the rulepack on the SSC server.

Comment: Just a note under Windows.  If the installation path is ex:  C:\Program Files\Fority\etc.  You need to wrap the path in "quotes" due to the space between "Program Files" throws off parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HP contract you have one or more rulepacks for one single language. For some languages you have only Core Coding Rules and for some you have additional "Extended" Coding Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Certain languages have both core & extended versions, but others are just one or the other. Specifically all the rulepacks are:

Core_abap
Core_actionscript
Core_android
Core_annotations
core_cfml
core_cobol
core_cpp
extended_cpp
core_dotnet
extended_dotnet
core_cobol
core_java
extended_java
core_javascript
core_objc
core_php
core_python
core_sql
extended_sql
core_vb
extended_config
extended_content
extended_jsp

Some languages may use multiple rulepacks for different reasons, but if you have javascript for example, then you need the javascript rulepacks. The basic contract will give you all of them except those for the premium languages which are paid for separately:

ColdFusion
ABAP
COBOL
Python